# Select :list in JPA not working,Spring MVC,Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a drop down as 'ALL', on click of which it passes a code to the controller.On receiving the code, the controller runs the query to pull the values as list and then pass this list for getting the result list.The list as debugged is being passed correctly, but it fails to retreive the result list which comes as 0. Controller Code is as below

```
List<CfBillCust> billCustList = manageCustService.getBuCustomers(buCde);
            System.out.println("BIll CUST LIST In COntoller" +billCustList.size());
            if (billCustList.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<CfBillCust>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<List<CfBillCust>>(billCustList, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Service Code as below

```
List<CfBillCust> billCustList=null;
        if(buCde.equals("99")){
            List<CfBu> buList=budao.getBuHavingProjectOrderByBuName();
            List<String> buLst=new ArrayList<String>(buList.size());
            for(CfBu cfBu: buList){
                buLst.add(String.valueOf(buList));
            }     
            billCustList = billCustDAO.getAllCustForBu(buLst);
        }
        else{
            billCustList = billCustDAO.getCustForBu(buCde);
        }
```

DAO code as below

```
List<CfBillCust> list = entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT b FROM CfBillCust b WHERE b.cfBu.buCde IN :buList ORDER BY billCustName")
                .setParameter("buList", buList).getResultList();
        System.out.println("BILL CUST DAO LIST " +list.size());
        return list;
```

Comment: why not share with people your debugging? like what SQL was issued to the database? (including any parameter values passed in to that SQL)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What are the debugging steps you have taken? Show some logs where you are getting some messages..